# Are there general formula for Reflexive Relation?

Tags: relations

I wonder if there is a general formula for Reflexive Relation ?

I wonder how to prove it if there is one.

Comment: This is not clear.  What are you asking?

Comment: how do you derived the reflexive formula 2^n2−n?

Comment: @lulu: ouch ! Without you, I would still be in the total dark...

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Yeah, this one was a stretch.